# Returning the python Script from particular line

Tags: python, excel, refresh

How Can i loop back the python script from particular line. This is about the refreshing an excel and I want to refresh it once in 2 hours.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import time
xlapp = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')

wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open('Excel path')
xlapp.visible = True
wb.RefreshAll()
time.sleep(10)
wb.Save()
wb.Close()
xlapp.Quit()
```

I don't want to close the excel file. So basically save it and loop back again after 2 hours and refresh and save... Repeat

How can I don that?

Comment: it is just my guess because I never use this lib, but maybe you can add while(true): before refreshAll and do the loop for RefreshAll, time.sleep, and Save

Comment: When I try to add While(true) I am getting "Invalid Syntax(plyflakes E)..

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already imported `time`, you could build a loop with `time.sleep(7200)` (7200 seconds being two hours) that keeps saving. Although I don'T think it's a good idea to keep the file open throughout that time. What speaks against closing and re-opening it after two hours?

Comment: Its because after Opening the Excel I manually need to connect to the CRM ( dynamic file) and then the refresh all needs to happen. If I close it I need to connect it all over again and this whole excel refresh is completly in the other system. So I would prefer it to be open and have the refresh in the loop.

But now how would you suggest me to add this loop?

Comment: I'd try a while True loop that has time.sleep(7200) in it and then, subsequently, runs a simple wb.Save() command. I noticed your earlier comment that "While(true)" doesn't work; in Python, the syntax is "while True:".

Comment: Thank you Schnitte, I got It working


`import win32com.client as win32
import time

xlapp = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')

wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open('Excel File')
xlapp.visible = True
time.sleep(20)
def refresh_excel():
 wb.RefreshAll()
 time.sleep(20)
 wb.Save()

while True:  
 refresh_excel()
 time.sleep(7200)
 wb.Save()`